# Eclipse Helios for RCP and RAD developers won't update to 3.6.2

Tags: eclipse

I got a strange behavior with an Eclipse installation:
Even though all update sites are there and accessible, and even though I can SEE in "Install New Software" dialog that there is the new Eclipse Platform 3.6.2.M20110210-1200 I cannot get it installed! Of course it says here that the original request has been modified:

```
Your original request has been modified.
  "Eclipse Platform" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Eclipse Platform 3.6.2.M20110210-1200  (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.6.2.M20110210-1200)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.rcp 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once:
```

But when I invoke "Check for Updates" it simply says "No updates were found."

Why?? How can I get it to the latest platform release?
Thanks!

Comment: might it be an issue with jdk? I tired openjdk and I'm not getting this error message anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the comments on [this bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=338310) correctly, the update or parts of it have currently been disabled because of an issue when updating Eclipse on Mac OS X. It seems you/we (I'm having a similar problem) can either wait for a bit or try using the update site mentioned in the comments:

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/helios/SR2.fixed

I haven't tried this myself, though.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you, that was exactly the solution I was looking for. It worked! Apparently only "RCP and RAD developers" edition of Eclipse was affected...

Comment: Glad to be of service. :-) At least the Java EE edition is also affected, though - that's why I came across this question in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is distributed by different packages, such as classic, SDK, CDT and Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers that one already installed or downloaded by you.

Eclipse platform is a part of those distribution, so you can installed it again.

You could enable/add the software repository(http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios) in your eclipse, then let it check the update. It should find the proper updates for you.

Comment: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios is already in my repositories and enabled. Still: no updates found! :-(

Comment: @Zordid, I did a query on the repository(http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios), there is no epp.package.rcp corresponding to SR2. It looks like it need some time to get the repository to be updated. Or open defect against epp.package.rcp.

Comment: The existing version of epp.package.rcp,

epp.package.rcp 1.3.0.20100617-0521

epp.package.rcp 1.3.1.20100916-1202